# Javascript - how to trigger a "if" condition by a change through CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm being tormented in the past 4 hours to find out how to do this, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I have a page with multiple layers, I wish to trigger some transition when the needed page has opacity 1, it should be simple when u think of it, here is my code, please help ;)

```js
slide1 = document.querySelector('.slide1');

function videoPlay() {
    var videoOne = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    if ((slide1.style.opacity) > 0 ) {
        videoOne.play();
    }
}
videoPlay();
```

```css
.slide {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
}
.slide1 {
    width: 100%;    
    background: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide slide1">
  <div class="slide-content">
    <div class="secondColumn">
      <video muted id="myVideo">
        <source src="Media/Acqua.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    <div class="lowerTab"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the code which i use to change the opacity using the wheel :

```js
//wheel event
    document.addEventListener('wheel',
function scrollWheel(event) {
var fig =event.deltaY;
if (fig > 0) {
    slideMove();
}
else if (fig<0) {
    slideMovReverse();
} 
})

//basic movement
 function slideMove() {
if (current === sliderImages.length-1 ) {
    current = -1
}
reset();
sliderImages[current+1].style.transition = "opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
sliderImages[current+1].style.opacity= "1.0"; 
current++;
}
```

Comment: I have never heard of listening to a CSS change in my short but extremely active 2 years in the industry (unless you poll the CSS state every x time and compare it with the state of the previous polls). Perhaps you should consider looking at the code that changes your opacity and do something after that?

Comment: thanks, the opacity changes with the mousewheel, I think i will do something with it, I didn't know it couldn't be done as I imagined though.

Comment: You should show us the code that changes the opacity. As it stands, your post is kind of vague and difficult to answer

Comment: I added it to the post,I hope that would make things clearer, I'm sorry about how vague I sound, I'm kinda new to this ^^''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `transitionend` event, but you'd have to set up the transition first.  As it sits now, there's not much information in your question about the different slides, how the transitions are set up, etc.  Here's a baseline to give you an idea:

```js
const slide1 = document.querySelector('.slide1');
const videoEl = document.querySelector('.slide1__video');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

let inView = false;

slide1.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
  let content = 'Playing';
  if (inView) {
    content = ''
  }
  videoEl.textContent = content;
  inView = !inView;
})

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  slide1.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.slide1 {
  transition: opacity 500ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 24px
}

.slide1.active {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="slide1">
  Slide 1
  <div class="slide1__video"></div>
</div>
<button>Next</button>
```

#### Edit

It'll need some love but I think it's in the right direction to what you're after.

```js
const slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'));

document.addEventListener('wheel', onScroll);

const SCROLL_TOLERANCE = 100;

let currentIndex = 0;
let currentScroll = 0;

function onScroll(e) {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    currentScroll += 1;
  } else {
    currentScroll -= 1;
  }

  if (currentScroll >= (currentIndex * SCROLL_TOLERANCE) + 15) {
    showNext();
  } else if (currentScroll <= (currentIndex * SCROLL_TOLERANCE) - 15) {
    showPrevious();
  }
}

function showNext() {
  if (currentIndex === slides.length - 1) {
    return console.warn('At the end.');
  }
  currentIndex += 1;
  setSlide();
}

function showPrevious() {
  if (currentIndex === 0) {
    return console.warn('At the beginning.');
  }
  currentIndex -= 1;
  setSlide();
}

function setSlide() {
  let newOpacity = 0;
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    if (+slide.dataset.index === currentIndex) {
      newOpacity = 1
    } else {
      newOpacity = 0;
    }
    slide.style.opacity = newOpacity;
    slide.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      console.log('Done transitioning!');
      // Do things here when the transition is over.
    })
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px
}

.slide {
  border: 3px solid #efefef;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 250ms;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide active" data-index="0">
  Slide 1
</div>
<div class="slide" data-index="1">
  Slide 2
</div>
<div class="slide" data-index="2">
  Slide 3
</div>
<div class="slide" data-index="3">
  Slide 4
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i added the rest of the code above to make things clearer in  what I'm doing :)

Comment: @ibrahimMohamed  I've amended my answer with a bit more.